# Where to place the capacitor when modelling a single long wire?

Tags: simulation, resistance, capacitance, equivalent-circuit

Consider a high-voltage power line that is hundreds of kilometers long. Such a wire has a capacitance, inductance and resistance.

[This answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/397069/360341) to a previous similar question contains the following simple model for such a wire:

[image: model of a single wire via a resistor, coil and a capacitor]

Let's assume that the resistance towards ground (Gdx) is infinite.

Let's also connect a (DC) voltage source to one side, and a consumer at the other side. The consumer could be a simple resistor. And let's consider the event of turning the voltage source on.

Now, the dynamics of this circuit must be different depending on if we place the voltage source on the left or on the right.
If placed on the left, the capacitor is charged more slowly, and if placed on the right, the capacitor is charged almost instantly.

**Question A:** is it true, that the circuit will behave differently depending on where the voltage source is placed?

**Question B:** if question A is true, then how can a wire be modeled more accurately. I would assume that it would be an infinite series of resistor-capacitor pairs? Is there a way to represent this with a small amount of elements? Is there some literature that has a solution to this problem?

Comment: Question B: Google Transmission line LC circuit, and no.

Comment: If the line is "only" (max) 300 km, you can use the simple model with one serial resistor-inductor as used in power distribution. If longer than 300 km, you must use another model (transmission line).

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve as in "Is there some literature that has a solution to this problem". I say this because you aren't really stating the problem in your question. In other words, depending on the (unstated) problem, the model may not be very appropriate at all so, state what the problem is that you are trying to solve.

Comment: @Antonio51 thank you for the numbers! I think then I'll just ignore capacitance. Simplifies this a lot.

Comment: @Andyaka I'm trying to simulate a power transmission network. But right now I am interested in the theory, such that I can make an informed decision on the model I want to use.

Comment: In that case then a single RLGC "lump" isn't much use to you without considering transmission-line theory. T-line theory uses a single "lump" and extracts what you might need to know but, not knowing what you need to know means I couldn't make an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it true, that the circuit will behave differently depending on where the voltage source is placed?

Yes.

If you need a symmetrical model, you could split either the series part or the parallel part in half, and move one half to the other end, making a series-parallel-series section (T-section) or parallel-series-parallel section (π-section).

Note that G is 'conductance', which is the inverse of resistance. When you split Gdx in half, the conductance halves, so the resistance doubles.

> how can a wire be modeled more accurately. I would assume that it would be an infinite series of resistor-capacitor pairs?

resistor-capacitor-resistor-inductor quadruplets, but yes

> Is there a way to represent this with a small amount of elements?

If you're using a computer simulator that can handle a *large* number of elements, you can halve all the quantities in this wire section (including half conductance = double resistance), then copy-paste another one connected to it. Then do it again, and again. As you increase the number of sections, the order of the components matters less and less.

Otherwise pick a way that makes sense for your situation. "All models are wrong, but some are useful." Modeling the line with the voltage source on the left could be a useful approximation of reality. Modeling it with the voltage source on the right isn't useful, because it neglects R and L. Putting the voltage source on the left is going to overplay the effect of R and L, just like putting it on the right underplays them, but it *could* be a useful approximation - I'm not authorized to know whether it actually is one.

If your simulator has a transmission line component, you can use that.

> Is there some literature that has a solution to this problem?

Probably [transmission line theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_line), e.g. [Telegrapher's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telegrapher%27s_equations).

Comment: Great! Thank you for the detailed clarifications.

Answer (score 3):

> Let's also connect a (DC) voltage source to one side, and a consumer at the other side.

At DC, the capacitors and inductors don't matter. You can replace the capacitors with open circuits and the inductors with short circuits.

For the transient that happens when the source is first connected, of course the capacitor and inductor do matter...but turn-on conditions with DC sources are rarely an issue with 1000-km are rarely a major consideration.

More often we use these models for steady-state AC analysis. (But of course Fourier analysis tells us that for linear systems we can analyze transient sources as combinations of sinusoidal ones)

> is it true, that the circuit will behave differently depending on where the voltage source is placed?

Yes, it's true. Even in AC analysis. If we put the source on the left, then as the AC frequency goes toward infinity the model becomes an open circuit, while if we put the source on the right it becomes a short circuit to ground. Both of these results are non-physical, you just have to choose which sort of non-physical result you want when you use the model outside its valid regime.

You could use Pi or T sections instead of the L sections you have now, if you want to have the same kind of error regardless of which end of the line the source is on.

> if question A is true, then how can a wire be modeled more accurately.

Break the line up into more, smaller sections and model each one separately.

> I would assume that it would be an infinite series of resistor-capacitor pairs? Is there a way to represent this with a small amount of elements?

You don't need to use an infinite number of sections. You only need enough sections that the model behaves sensibly at your operating frequency. Using even 10 sections per wavelength gives reasonable results (so roughly one section per 500 km when operating at 60 Hz), and 20 or more sections per wavelength should give quite accurate results.

If you want this to work for your step input transient scenario you need to limit the risetime of the input and choose a transmission line model appropriate for the frequency band needed to construct a step input with that risetime from sinusoids. This will be roughly up to frequencies of \$1/t_R\$.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, especially about the discretisation along the x-axis

Answer (score 2):

Please be aware of the "dx": The actual model consists of many infinitesimal small circuits like the one you have drawn. Usually the units of the circuit elements aren't "Ohms" or "Farads", either. They are "Ohms per Meter", for example.

For a more accurate representation you need to introduce another circuit element called "transmission line". The fundamental difference between a transmission line and all other circuit elements like resistors and capacitors is time delay.

Comment: Thank you for the keywords!

Answer (score 0):

> Question A: is it true, that the circuit will behave differently depending on where the voltage source is placed?

No.  Note the "dx" in the circuit diagram: this is an infinitely small element of the line.  As such, the serial components of this element are too small to make a difference to the action of the parallel elements.

Expressed in terms of a transmission matrix, this is represented as

\${V_1\choose I_1}=\begin{pmatrix}1&(R+Ls)dx\\(G+Cs)dx&1\end{pmatrix}{V_2\choose I_2}\$

and you approximate an infinite product of those (which is done via Eigenvector decomposition that allows you to convert the product into a sum).

That's the basics of transmission line theory.  It doesn't really matter which end you put the parallel elements on since a single element is not different from a unity matrix anyway: it's just the accumulation of an infinite number of those elements that shows a final result, and between any two serial elements is a parallel element.  Whether there is one at the left or the right end or both or none, doesn't make a difference because it is just a single element.